# MySQL error code needed

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, http-status-code-404

MySQL always sends a "default response" even when the data doesn't match the query!

How can I design my query to get an error code from MySQL if no data is matching the query?

I need an error code from MySQL to create a 404 or 410 page.

```
SELECT
place.ID AS id,
place.latitude AS lat,
place.longitude AS lng,

IF(
place.translationID IS NULL,
place.name,
placel10n.text
) AS cityname,

IF(
admcode.translationID IS NULL,
'',
statel10n.text
) AS statename,

IF (  
countrycode.translationID IS NULL,
countrycode.name,
countryl10n.Text
) AS countryname,

IF(
place.textID IS NULL,
'',
`l10n-strings`.text
) AS description

FROM
places AS place

LEFT JOIN `l10n-strings` AS placel10n ON (place.translationID = placel10n.translationID         AND placel10n.languageCode = 'de')
LEFT JOIN admin1codesascii AS admcode ON (place.admin1 = admcode.statecode AND     place.country = admcode.country)
LEFT JOIN `l10n-strings` AS statel10n ON (admcode.translationID =    statel10n.translationID AND statel10n.languageCode = 'de')
LEFT JOIN countries AS countrycode ON (place.country = countrycode.iso_alpha2)
LEFT JOIN `l10n-strings` AS countryl10n ON (countrycode.translationID =    countryl10n.TranslationID AND countryl10n.LanguageCode = 'de')

LEFT JOIN texts ON (place.textID = texts.id)
LEFT JOIN `l10n-strings` ON (texts.translationID = `l10n-strings`.translationID AND    `l10n-strings`.languageCode= 'de')

WHERE
place.id = '8'
AND
place.featurecode = 'A'
OR
place.featurecode = 'AB'
OR
place.featurecode = 'AAC'

LIMIT 0,1
```

This query always returns a result even when the `where` statements are wrong.

Comment: This SQL query is embedded in what language?  PHP, Perl, C#, Java, ...?

Comment: I use PHP for that ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the way SQL works.  If there are no rows that match your query, the result set will be empty.  It's the job of the program (written in PHP or what have you) in which your SQL query is embedded to respond to the "no rows" case and change the response status (to 404 or what have you).  SQL queries are not responsible for HTTP status codes -- it's chalk and cheese.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I know that MYSQL not is responsible for my HTTP header codes, but this query standing above always sends a result.. not  NULL rows, but with a "real" result

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, [AND has higher operator precedence than OR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), so the conditions in your WHERE clause will be interpreted as

```
(place.id = '8' AND place.featurecode = 'A') OR
place.featurecode = 'AB' OR 
place.featurecode = 'AAC'
```

Use parentheses to be explicit about the order of operation you intend.  Perhaps you meant this?

```
place.id = '8' AND 
   (place.featurecode = 'A' OR 
    place.featurecode = 'AB' OR 
    place.featurecode = 'AAC')
```